# jQuery simple expression with || but with unclear result

Tags: javascript, jquery, boolean, expression, boolean-operations

I'm curious why the jQuery expression

`$("#mydiv").find(".myitem1") || $("#mydiv").find(".myitem2");` returns `[]` if:
 `.myitem1` doesn't exist on the page. Also, `$("#mydiv").find(".myitem2")` DOES exist, the result is a non-empty object.

I expect to get the result that is the first expression if it exists otherwise the second one. As you see I use `||`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `.find()` always returns a jQuery collection (not an array), which both are *never* falsy.

Comment: you will have to use a ternary operator here `$("#mydiv").find(".myitem1").length ? $("#mydiv").find(".myitem1") : $("#mydiv").find(".myitem2");` - if possible cache the value of `$("#mydiv").find(".myitem1")`

Comment: @Arun P Johny: That is one place you should not recommend a ternary as you run the initial selector twice. Caching it is a good idea. Maybe better off with a simple `if` :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie I had added an additional comment about caching the result (if possible cache the value of $("#mydiv").find(".myitem1"))

Comment: @Arun P Johny: Noted in revised comment and used your suggestion for 3rd option below. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The explanations of why it fails are in the comments, but, given the logic you are attempting, why not just use this (if they are in the page in sequential order):

```
 $("#mydiv").find(".myitem1,.myitem2").first();
```

otherwise use:

```
var $result = $("#mydiv").find(".myitem1");
if (!$result.length){
    $result = $("#mydiv").find(".myitem2");
}
```

Do not use a ternary expression as-is as it will run the first selector twice. Use a ternary like this:

```
var $result = $("#mydiv").find(".myitem1");
$result = $result.length ? $result : $("#mydiv").find(".myitem2");
```

Your current code assumes `find` returns nothing if a match isn't found, but that is not how jQuery allows for chaining of methods. It will always return a jQuery object (just an empty one for no matches). This allows jQuery code like `$('#youCantMatchThis').text();` to return an empty string and not give an error.

Comment: Thank you everybody for possible solutions. I've found $("#mydiv").find(".myitem1,.myitem2").first(); the best as it is short, clear, doesn't use the selector twice and that's what I need. Thank you everybody.